# Book that contains a future human race that abandons Earth to escape aliens?

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I remember a friend telling me about this book series a few years ago. I don't know when it was released though.

Things I remember:

- Humans left Earth in space ships to escape an alien race that was coming to destroy them because of their technological advances.
- The humans colonize a new planet and ban technology so the aliens won't come destroy them.
- There is a robot like thing that eventually becomes "Merlin" in the book series. This was a technology back on the original Earth that people could transfer their consciousness into temporary to go do things like extreme sports and the like.
- The word "Storm" maybe in the name? Not sure on this one...
- Some of the people that originally left Earth became "angels" to the people on the new planet. I think maybe memory erasing may have been a thing here.
- At one point someone detonates a nuke destroying most of these "angels" and their ships. Pocket nuke? Or a briefcase maybe.
- There is a church that, in the "modern day" which I think is thousands of years after the fleeing from aliens, hardcore goes against people that are inventing technology. Think Spanish Inquisition.

I haven't actually read the book so I'm not sure if these are correct.

Comment: Some of these tropes match the Council Wars series of books; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Council_Wars

Comment: @Valorum Hmm that could be it. I will investigate that series further. Thank you.

Comment: There's enough dissimilarity that I'm hesitant to post it as an answer, but let me know if it's the one (with other unrelated stuff) mixed in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like the Safehold series by David Weber which began with [Off Armageddon Reef](http://www.davidweber.net/books/43-off-armageddon-reef.html) in 2007 and continued for at least nine volumes total. (The link provided connects to the David Weber website and there are summaries of all the volumes there.)  Wikipedia also gas a [good description of the series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safehold)

The match to your description is pretty good: Humans left Earth which was destroyed by aliens. Merlin is a human consciousnesses in an android body, at the colony's foundation there were "archangels" who used technology to dominate the colonists, and by the time of the story there's certainly a church with quasi-inquisitors which was set up to keep technology from restarting.  I can't match the "Storm" item from what I've read -- but there's plenty of *sturm und drang*!.

Comment: Although it's usually good form to provide matching passages or matching descriptions, I'll endorse this answer, as I've read the series and it is point for point the answer to the question.

Comment: Can you explain what about these books match the description given in the question

Comment: Another of David Weber's books has the word "Storm" in the title; https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1439133549/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=bsio-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=1439133549

Comment: This is definitely it.

Comment: @jeklund - In which case it's a dupe and will be closed shortly. Good on you for finding it :-)

Comment: @Valorum Sounds good. Thanks!